# Short-circuiting "uninteresting" cases in monadic computation

Tags: syntax, pattern-matching, monads, agda

I have a function which uses `Data.Maybe.monad` like this:

```
typeCheck ν (f · e) =
  typeCheck ν e >>= λ { (u , e′) →
  typeCheck ν f >>= λ { (u′ ▷ t , f′) →
  u !≡ₜ u′      >>= λ { refl →
  pure (, (f′ · e′)) };
  _ → nothing }}
```

Is there a way to either eliminate the `_ → nothing` case, or at least move it further up (similar to Idris) to get something similar to the following:

```
typeCheck ν (f · e) =
  typeCheck ν e >>= λ { (u , e′) →
  typeCheck ν f >>= λ { _ → nothing; (u′ ▷ t , f′) →
  u ≡!ₜ u′      >>= λ { refl →
  pure (, (f′ · e′)) }}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agda now has [do-notation](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language/syntactic-sugar.html#do-notation). An example from the documentation:

```
infer Γ (app e e₁) = do
  s ofType A => B ← infer Γ e
    where _ ofType nat → typeError "numbers cannot be applied to arguments"
  t ofType A₁     ← infer Γ e₁
  refl            ← A =?= A₁
  pure (app s t ofType B)
```